# When I run script in vs code, cypress is run but I can't see my project in cypress list to click and complete the automation

Tags: automation, cypress

I wrote my automation in Vs code and ran it with Cypress open. I can't find my project in Cypress to click and run the test.

How can I push my script to cypress?

Comment: Did you include your test inside the `integration` folder or maybe altered what files should be picked up as tests within `cypress.json`?

Answer (score 0):

In Cypress.json file make sure testFiles array has your correct spec file names or you can remove testFiles configuration, so that it displays all the Spec files which are in the Integration folder.

```
 "testFiles": ["Register.spec.js","Login.spec.js","Home.spec.js","ContactUs.spec.js","NewAccount.spec.js","FundTransfer.spec.js","BillPayment.spec.js","RequestLoan.spec.js","E2E.spec.js"]
```

[image]

Also make sure the Integration Folder is set to correct path (Refer screenshot below) you can make this configuration in Cypress.json file

[image]